# Is qiskit_backend_monitor magic function deprecated?

Tags: qiskit

I've upgraded qiskit for the first time in a while and I've discovered that the magic function for displaying backend information doesn't seem to work properly.

Here's what I've tried running:

```
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
backend = P[1].get_backend('ibmq_poughkeepsie')
%qiskit_backend_overview
```

This returns a ZeroDivisionError.

I've also tried calling backend_monitor(backend), but returns a TypeError, saying that 'module' object is not callable.

I've tried looking into what kind of changes might have been made to the library for monitoring backends, but I cannot seem to find the answer I'm looking for. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%qiskit_backend_overview` magic is not deprecated and has seen updates for the most recent 0.11.0 release: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/tools/jupyter/backend_overview.py to ensure it works with new devices. The ZeroDivisionError might point to a bug in the code for the function or in your calling code, without a full traceback and all code you're running it's hard to know for sure.

I did test it with the latest version qiskit 0.14.1 locally and it still works fine for me:

[image: backend overview]

As for backend monitor that also looks fine to me (it doesn't need a magic anymore as the html representation in jupyter for an ibmq backend object is formatted the same way since the qiskit-terra 0.9.0 release):

[image: backend monitor]

If the graphical jupyter backends aren't working for you for whatever reason there are always the python functions from `qiskit.tools` that do the same thing just without any of the graphical output. For example:

[image: backend monitor function]